# OSMNX shortest path analysis: osmnx.nearest_nodes() returns ValueError: Input contains NaN, although the geodataframes fed into the Graph have no NULL

Tags: openstreetmap, osmnx

I am trying to get the shortest path by rail between two cities.
I have two geopandas dataframes with edges and nodes. Neither contain NANs.
[gdf_edges.head(2)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Tda6.png)
[gdf_nodes.head(2)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7triL.png)

Please advise how to fix this error:

```
import osmnx as ox

G = ox.graph_from_gdfs( gdf_nodes, gdf_edges.set_index(['FRFRANODE', 'TOFRANODE', 'FRAARCID']), graph_attrs=None )

source = ox.nearest_nodes(G, X=40.694384761057826, Y=-74.011049120926) 
target = ox.nearest_nodes(G, X=33.755099145658, Y=-118.19061812233898)
```

This returns the following error message:

```
ValueError: Input contains NaN, infinity or a value too large for dtype('float64').
```

If I could get the source and the target nodes, the remaining code to compute the shortest distance should work as follows:

```
weight = "MILES"
route = nx.shortest_path( G, source, target, weight=weight)
route_length = nx.shortest_path_length( G, source, target, weight)
```

By the way, here is how I checked for NAN in the dataframes:
gdf_edges.isnull().any()
gdf_nodes.isnull().any()

Comment: You checked if it contains NaN, but did you also check if it contains infinity or a value too large to store in a 64 bit float (as per the error message)? Also, your code snippet isn't self contained, so we can't reproduce it to troubleshoot.

Comment: Thank you kindly for your prompt response. 

Please help me understand this better. 
1) What's the best way to share a huge dataset of rail tracks? If I share a small subset, the locations I feed into the function won't be in the small subset

2) I am not sure how 'float' is an issue:

gdf_nodes.dtypes
FRANODEID       int64
geometry     geometry

gdf_edges.dtypes
FRAARCID        int64
FRFRANODE       int64
TOFRANODE       int64
geometry     geometry

3) G=create_ox_graph(
gdf_nodes.set_index('FRANODEID') , 
gdf_edges.set_index(['FRAARCID', 'FRFRANODE', 'TOFRANODE']))
)

Comment: You should generate a minimal, self-contained code snippet to reproduce your issue without relying on a huge dataset. Often, doing this will enable you to solve your own problem.